# How to check if a checkbox is checked or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes and in my controller i want to be able to know if those checkboxes are checked or not.
My code :

in .h :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet Checkbox *option1Button;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet Checkbox *option2Button;
```

in controller.m:

```
- (IBAction)optionButton1Pressed:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"first : %lu second : %lu", (unsigned long)[_option1Button state], (unsigned long)[_option2Button state]);
}

- (IBAction)optionButton2Pressed:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"first : %lu second : %lu", (unsigned long)[_option1Button state], (unsigned long)[_option2Button state]);
}
```

The action mapped is "touch up inside". 
And what i can see in the logs is that state is always 1 if i check or uncheck the checkboxes. Everytime that i click, it's a 1

I've tried with "editing changed" but it's never called

Any idea?

Comment: What is `Checkbox`? That's not a standard iOS class.

Comment: No matter what language or platform, you could always set a boolean that changes every time the check is changed.  Simple.

Comment: Oh crap sry i'm pretty new to objective c, just saw that, this extends UIButton...

Comment: Then you're going to want to check the `state` property. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSButton/state

Comment: Add tag values to your uibutton

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume checkbox is derived from UIButton... in which case it would be the `state`...

so `option1Button.state & UIControlStateSelected` would probably do what you want...

FYI:

```
enum {
   UIControlStateNormal               = 0,
   UIControlStateHighlighted          = 1 << 0,
   UIControlStateDisabled             = 1 << 1,
   UIControlStateSelected             = 1 << 2,
   UIControlStateApplication          = 0x00FF0000,
   UIControlStateReserved             = 0xFF000000 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends why you want to know the state.

*(I will assume you have configured the state of your button to display a checkbox image if it is in a selected state, and an empty box otherwise.)*

If the following is why

```
if (!button.isSelected) {
   button.selected = YES;
}
```

Then asking the button's 'isSelected property is a good way to find out if the button is showing a checkmark.

However, if for example the following is why you want to know the state

```
if (button.isSelected) {
    //Send network request
}
```

Then asking your button is not the right way to find out if the checkmark is checked. The reason for this is because your should be writing your app with a strict conformance to the design paradigm 'model-view-controller' or MVC.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller

So if your button is checked because of the following (for example)

```
if (x > 5) {
    button.checked = YES;
}
```

Then asking your model if x is greater than 5 is the best way to determine if the checkmark button is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)optionButton1Pressed:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

   if(btn.isSelected)
       btn.isSelected = NO;

   else
       btn.isSelected = YES;
}
```